# POSIXct and varying time zones

Tags: r

I am working with a large dataset (100k observation) of times using the as.POSIXct function.

The times however have two different time zones:

```
"Thu Jan 17 09:29:10 EST 2013"
"Sun Mar 10 21:31:28 EDT 2013"
```

I'm trying to put them into the same time zone and format so I can find the time distance between them. I do this as follows:

```
as.POSIXct("Thu Jan 17 09:29:10 EST 2013", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EST %Y")

as.POSIXct("Sun Mar 10 21:31:28 EDT 2013", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EDT %Y")
```

I want to do this conversion in bulk. To do this, I set up the following if function:

```
mydata$converteddate = numeric(length(mydata$dates))

for (i in seq_along(mydata$converteddate)) {
  if (grepl("EST",mydata$dates[i])) mydata$converteddate[i]=as.POSIXct(mydata$dates, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EST %Y")
  if (grepl("EDT",mydata$dates[i])) mydata$converteddate[i]=as.POSIXct(mydata$dates, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EDT %Y")-(60*60)}
```

This has ran for the last few hours, which seems like it shouldn't be the case. Is there a faster to go about this? Note that the 60*60 part converts EDT to EST.

EDIT: to clarify, my main question is not the time zone question, but how to loop through the dataset in an efficient manner to convert all the dates into a usable format. I walked away from my computer for 5 hours and it was still running for 100k cases.

Comment: Those are the same time zone; `EDT` just designates that daylight savings is in effect. For example, `as.POSIXct("2013-03-09 01:01:00", tz = "America/New_York") + (24 * 3600) * (0:2)`.

Comment: Or better yet, `as.POSIXct("2013-03-10 01:59:59", tz = "America/New_York") + 0:2`.

Comment: My question isn't necessarily the time zone question but how loop through to convert all of them. The other issue is that I'm working with cycle times for this process which I calculate by taking the difference between two dates. If one is in EDT and the other is in EST, a conversion is necessary, correct? Is there a better way to run through the all the data for conversion?

Comment: If I understand, `c(as.POSIXct(grep("EDT", mydata$dates, value = TRUE), format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EDT %Y"),
as.POSIXct(grep("EST", mydata$dates, value = TRUE), format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EST %Y"))` should work; no looping necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is the input character vector, remove the time zone first using `sub` and specify it using `tz`:

```
as.POSIXct(sub("E.T ", "", x), format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", tz = "EST5EDT")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with the `anytime()` function of the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package.

The format you encounter is not *yet* supported by default (though I will add this).

It is however *really* easy to add to the current release 0.2.0 as well:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anytime::addFormats("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S% xxx %Y")  # adding it
R> anytime("Thu Jan 17 09:29:10 EST 2013")
[1] "2013-01-17 09:29:10 CST"
R>
```

The key here is that we add the desired format with its 'xxx' flag to hide the timezone information.  As the comments above already told you, the EST and EDT are just illustrative.  Here we get CST as I in the Central timezone.

The performance should also help you as the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package uses performant C++ code under the hood:

```
R> bigvec <- rep("Thu Jan 17 09:29:10 EST 2013", 100000L)
R> system.time(res <- anytime(bigvec))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.600   0.164   0.767 
R>
```

That about 3/4 of a second for 100,000 conversions on my older, lower-clockspeed server.